# Changing a mark in a college database file in C

Tags: c, file

So I have this code, a function for changing a mark in a college database.
So we need to get the class number and for each student in that class we change the first mark, and save it later in the same file.
e.g. we get the class 1026
Andrew has those marks(numbers, 1 to 10):4,6,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,10
Helen got:10,6,8,7,7,6,6,7,9,10
After we call the function we will get:
Andrew: 10,6,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,10
Helen 5,6,8,7,7,6,6,7,9,10
However, after the first student in that class, the reading of the new first mark for the second will repeat infinitely, and I can't figure it out.
Here is the code:

```
typedef struct{
    char is;//this will help us to see if the registration number exist in the file(0-if false, 1-if true)
    int nrmat;//registration number
    char name[20];
    int year;
    int class;
    float mark[10];
}stud;

void new_mark(char name_file[20])
{
    FILE *f;
    stud a;
    int class, mark;
    if(!(f=fopen(name_file,"rb+"))) printf("no file found");
    else {  
            printf("\nclass = ");scanf("%d",&class);
            while(!feof(stdin))
            {
                rewind(f);
                fread(&a,sizeof(stud),1,f);
                while(!feof(f))
                {
                    if(a.is == 1 && a.class == class)
                    {
                        printf(a.name);printf("\n\n");
                        printf("the new mark is: ");scanf("%d", &mark);
                        a.mark[0] = mark;
                        fseek(f,(a.nrmat-1)*sizeof(stud),0);
                        fwrite(&a,sizeof(stud),1,f);
                    }
                fread(&a,sizeof(stud),1,f);
                }
            printf("\nclass = ");scanf("%d",&class);
            }
    fclose(f);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Error messages should be useful.  Replace `if(!(f=fopen(name_file,"rb+"))) printf("no file found");` with `if(!(f=fopen(name_file,"rb+"))) perror(name_file);`

Comment: You never check if `mark` is successfully read, nor do you ensure any of the `fread()` or `fwrite()` calls work.

Comment: 1st, why are you checking for `feof(stdin)`.  2nd, why are you rewinding?

Comment: You seek to a.nrmat, and then read the next dataum from f.  Are the values in a.nrmat monotonically increasing?  Are they correct?  Seems like you could easily get into a cycle there.

Comment: Declare arguments in a more abstract way like `char* x` instead of `char x[20]` as you don't necessarily want to limit lengths like that. Try and use `char*` in preference to fixed-length buffers whenever possible.

Comment: @jiveturkey because I want to ask the user to enter more class numbers, and to exit he needs to press ctrl+Z three times.
Rewind for every different class entered by the user, so the file content is checked from beginning.

Comment: I think @WilliamPursell is on the right track.